# Jquery file upload. Failed to resize image (original thumbnail)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I'm using [jquery file upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and want to apply it to my site. So, I unzipped archive and uploaded it's content on server (I'm using php). I can see demo page there, also I've chmoded directory /server/php/files to 777. Files are succesfully uploaded to directory. Also I can see thumbnails of uploaded pictures, when I add them:
[image: Adding of images].
But when I use start upload button it uploads file but stops displaying thumbnails and gives me folowing mistake.
[image: Mistake]
Has anyone met that mistake? Any suggestions?
**UPDATE:**
Here is initialization:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'server/php/UploadHandler.php',
    disableImageResize : false,
    process: [
        {
            action: 'load',
            fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
            maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
        },
        {
            action: 'resize',
            maxWidth: 1920,
            maxHeight: 1200,
            minWidth: 20,
            minHeight: 10
        },
        {
            action: 'save'
        }
    ],
});
```

**UPDATE1:**
I've added attribute data-url to the same uploader to form and to it's action. Now I get mistake:  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: have you got any console errors whn u click the start btn..??

Comment: Nope, console is empty.

Comment: Have you tried setting `disableImageResize` to false

Comment: Also, I have another issue with using it at site(not in demo category). I'll create a question and post link here.

Comment: could you try reducing the parameters like Width and Height

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69425/discussion-between-sergey-scopin-and-outlooker).

Answer (score 3):

@Snoozer right, I also had the same issue, I am using php v7 and after enable the `gd` extension its fixed.

you should open your php.ini file and uncomment this line:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Update for the comment that I've read in the options array:

```
        // Set to 0 to use the GD library to scale and orient images,
        // set to 1 to use imagick (if installed, falls back to GD),
        // set to 2 to use the ImageMagick convert binary directly:
        'image_library' => 1,
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it was the gd extension or imagick extension was not installed in my php server.

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem on one of Heroku servers and just fixed this by adding

```
    "ext-gd": "*",
```

to composer.json file require section, hope this will help some one in the future.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd

## or

sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd

## or

sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
Can solove the question

Answer (score -2):

Give 777 permissions to folder to which ur uploading files.
sudo chmod 777 -R folderpath
it solved for me